# How to prevent suspended app from being wiped out of memory?

Tags: ios5, memory-management

In IOS5 - If my app gets suspended, can I somehow prevent it from being  wiped out from memory if IOS requires the memory?
If it does get wiped out, can I ask IOS to put it again in suspended state after it regains the memory back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. The memory is under control of the watch dog.

Instead make your app preserves the last state to speed up the next start. Then it seems for the user that the app wasn't ever killed.

Answer (score 0):

Ios will only kill your app if you use TOO MUCH memory ... other wise it will never be killed so try to keep your memory consupmtion very low. Instead of alocating memory try to use mmap insted